# SQL: How do I limit only one date per row returned?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an MDM that has iPhones reporting their inventory. I want to run a query to get their IP address history for the year of 2014. My goal was to get one row, per device, per day. I currently have a query that is returning multiple rows per day because of how often they are reporting their IP to the MDM. For example:

```
display_name   device_name         ip_address   date_entered
john_smith     john_smiths_iphone  10.1.0.122   2014-05-27 12:36:44
john_smith     john_smiths_iphone  10.1.0.122   2014-05-27 13:34:25
john_smith     john_smiths_iphone  10.1.0.122   2014-05-27 14:12:34
john_smith     john_smiths_iphone  10.1.0.122   2014-05-27 22:56:51
john_smith     john_smiths_iphone  10.1.0.122   2014-05-27 23:06:02
```

I would like only the first entry per day, per device, for the year 2014.

This is the query I'm currently running:

```sql
SELECT iphone_details.display_name
,      iphone_details.device_name
,      iphone_details.ip_address
,      reports.date_entered 
FROM   iphone_details
,      reports 
WHERE  date_entered LIKE "%2014%"
```

The `iphone_details` table has the columns:`display_name`, `device_name`, and `ip_address`
The `reports` table has `date_entered`

This query is resulting in too many rows returned. I was running this query from mySQL Workbench and was getting an error. Turned out it was because the /tmp directory on my server was filling up. So I ran the query directly from the mySQL server via CLI and outputted the results to a file with `INTO OUTFILE` and once I saw the output file hit 22G, I stopped the query.

I'd appreciate any direction or help with a query that could limit the results. Thanks!

EDIT:
I found there is a "report_id" that both the `iphone_details` and `reports` have. Could that be used to `JOIN` them?

Comment: what column links `reports` to `iPhone_details`? You didn't join on anything.

Comment: By "first entry" do you mean the earliest timestamp, or something else?

Comment: Removed the [sql-Server] tag, because the question is about MySQL

Comment: Try to use an ORDER BY and LIMIT to restrict the query response:

SELECT iphone_details.display_name, iphone_details.device_name, iphone_details.ip_address, reports.date_entered 
FROM iphone_details, reports WHERE date_entered LIKE "%2014%" ORDER BY date_entered ASC LIMIT 1

Comment: Your query will return one row for each entry in the reports table where date_entered like '%2014%' (let's say this returns 1000 rows) times however many rows are in the iphone_details table (for our example, let's say 100,000 rows).  This would output 100,000,000 rows.  You need to join the 2 tables on a relevant piece of data to get a reasonable result.  You need to find keys in the data

Comment: Don't use `LIKE` for doing date lookup.  `LIKE` is for matching patterns in strings, not for comparing dates.  There are more appropriate ways of querying date columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are some problems with your JOIN, namely that you have no relationship between reports and iphone_details and so EVERY permutation of EVERY row in both tables will be returned, the following will help you

```
SELECT 
    d.device_id,
    d.display_name, 
    d.device_name, 
    d.ip_address, 
    DATE(reports.date_entered) AS just_date_entered
FROM iphone_details AS d
INNER JOIN reports AS r
    ON r.report_id= d.report_id
    AND r.date_entered >= DATE('2014-01-01') 
    AND r.date_entered < DATE('2015-01-01')
GROUP BY
    d.device_id,
    d.ip_address,
    just_date_entered
```

Firstly the change to do date_entered BETWEEN  AND  (this will match up to 2014-12-31 23:59:59) is more efficient than doing a full-text search on a datetime field.

Secondly the DATE(reports.date_entered) allows for just the date section of the datetime field to be extracted.

Thirdly the GROUP BY ensures only distinct combinations of device, ip address, and date are returned.

( edited to reflect new information below )

Comment: without something to join on, this won't do much though.

Comment: It won't have added some advice on that score to the end - feels like the table split has been put in the wrong place partially.  Possibility for a third table so iphone_details, reports, and report_entries.

Comment: `BETWEEN` is inclusive; you're matching an extra day.

Comment: Well actually an extra second if you want to be picky, depending what accuracy you record, as DATE('2015-01-01') == 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 -> updated to be a >= and < for the sake of millisecond accuracy

Comment: Sorry- I found that there is a `report_id` on both the `iphone_details` and `reports` tables. Can we use that to `JOIN` them?

Comment: It's not an extra second, it's an extra day, because the OP's field is `DATETIME`. Go ahead, try `SELECT DATE('2015-01-01 23:59:59') BETWEEN DATE('2014-01-01') AND DATE('2015-01-01')`.

Comment: Hi AirThomas please note that I didn't do DATE() around the DATETIME for that precise reason + also due to the fact that doing so would trigger a table scan.  A DATE() is handled as 00:00:00.000 and so it's by including your DATETIME in DATE() that your match there happens.  That is all.

Answer (score 0):

This should make it so it only shows the most recent record for each device name.

```
WITH CTE as
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over
        (partition by iphone_details.device_name
            ORDER by date_entered) as rowno,
        iphone_details.display_name, iphone_details.ip_address, iphone_details.date_entered
        FROM SCHEMA.iphone_details
        WHERE iphone_details.date_entered LIKE "%2014%"
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rowno = 1
```